# A reference for Nielsen's First Generalized Polynomial Expansion

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

In Henry Gould's Combinatorical identities the following appears under the name Nielsen's First Generalized Polynomial Expansion: Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^na_k x^k$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and let $n\leq m$. Then

$$f(x+y)=(-1)^{m}\sum_{k=0}^{m+1}\binom{x+k-1}{m}\sum_{j=0}^{k}(-1)^{j}\binom{m+1}{j}f(j-k+y).$$ It took me some time to understand that Nielsen refers to Niels Nielsen (and not to Jakob Nielsen).

Can someone please state the exact reference where this identity is taken from?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I have found everything I wanted and even more in the book
Combinatorial Identities for Stirling Numbers by Jocelyn Quaintance and H. W. Gould.

The identity may be derived from results by Nielsen that goes back at least to
Trait´e ´el´ementaire des nombres de Bernoulli by N. Nielsen, 1923.